# postgresql connection with pgadmin4 shows all databases on the same domain

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have created 2 postgresql databases, 1 in the main domain and another one in the subdomain of the same domain. they both have different username and passwords. I have logged in with pgadmin 4 to subdomain database but  i was surprised to see that i saw both databases in the domain. is this normal or i need to create different user privilages?

Comment: What do you mean by "domain" and "subdomain"?